# how to store more than 5 authentication token in keychain iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, keychain

I wanted to store some sensitive data in keychain.I have to store almost 7 tokens in the keychain.

Im able to store one token using  `[keychainItem setObject:@"password you are saving" forKey:kSecValueData];`this method.(I used the `KeychainItemWrapper` opensource)

In case of `NSUserdefaults` we can store many tokens by changing the keyvalue,but it is not secure.

Also is there any limit for storing the values in keychain.

So can anyone please tell me how to store many tokens using keychain feature in iOS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At the initialization of the KeychainWrapper, I guess you're setting an Indentifier. It could be a idea to get various identifier.

Comment: @Larme work like a charm.Please post it as answer so i can accept it :).Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `KeychainWrapper` is initialized with an `Identifier`, a possible way to store more tokens (or else) is to have various Identifiers.